# How to do a each inside a each in jquery?

Tags: jquery, replace, iteration, each, jquery-templates

I have this json object :

```
{
"msg_id":"134",
"message":"Dick",
"comment":[
    {
    "com_id":"9",
    "comment":"test",
    "msg_id":"134",
    },
    {
    "com_id":"10",
    "comment":"testtt",
    "msg_id":"134",
    },
    {
    "com_id":"11",
    "comment":"testtttt",
    "msg_id":"134",
    }]
},
{
"msg_id":"134",
"message":"Dick",
},
{
"msg_id":"134",
"message":"Dick",
}
```

And I'm trying to iterate through it twice. Once for the main json object and then for the `comment` one.

I tried this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, obj){
    msg += template.replace( /{{message}}/ig  , obj.message )
                   .replace( /{{msg_id}}/ig   , obj.msg_id );

    $.each(obj.comment, function(key, val){
            msg += template.replace( /{{comment}}/ig , val.comment )
                   .replace( /{{com_id}}/ig , val.com_id )
                   .replace( /{{msg_id}}/ig , val.msg_id );           
    });   
});
```

If I do this I get `a is undefined jquery.js line 2`. Maybe I need to create another function for the second loop.

Comment: Please publish your full JS code , specifically line 2 :)

Comment: I think some json errors. You can see the erros at jsonlint.com

Comment: *"i have this json object"* The quoted text is invalid [JSON](http://json.org). JSON has to have a **single** top-level object (either an object, `{...}`; or an array, `[...]`). This probably relates to the trouble you're having. What you've quoted would be valid if it had a `[` at the beginning and a `]` at the end. [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) is a handy place to validate JSON, which is usually the first step to diagnosing this sort of problem. :-)

Comment: the json validates ok. I believe the way i do the each loop might not be proper.

Comment: "I find your lack of Caps disturbing." - Darth Vader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably just a `obj.comment` being undefined (note that you don't have any comments in the last two messages), add this:

```
if(obj.comment) {
}
```

around the inner `.each` call, i.e. make it something like this:

```
$.each(messages, function(i, msg) {
    if(msg.comment) {
        $.each(msg.comment, function(i, comment) {
            $('#log').append($('<div>').text(comment.comment));
        });
    }
});
```

Working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/T8BX7/

Comment: yeah, looks like i forgot to check for that. seems to be working now.